# Does VisualStudio provide a way to view textures?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, graphics, directx, textures

I am creating a DirectX texture programatically and binding it to a shader. I would like to verify that the texture appears as expected. Does Visual Studio 2012 or some other tool provide a method of viewing a texture? I could render the thing but that will take a bit of work and if there's an existing solution I would prefer to use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In Visual Studio 2012** When using graphics debugger ( Main menu -> Debug -> Graphics -> Start Diagnostic ( Alt+F5) ), capture the frame (Print Screen), then in "Object table" choose your resource (SRV, UAV or buffer), on opened tab click link.
The only thing I doubt is in which editions graphics debugger avaliable.

**[NVIDIA Nsight](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nsight.html)** has similar functionality, but it is not supporting VS 2012 yet. You can use v2.0 or v3.0 RC in VS 2010 if you have NVIDIA hardware.

**[AMD](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/gpu-perfstudio-2/)** has its own toolset too, but I've never use it. You can try if you have AMD Radeon onboard.

And, as Robert J. stated, good old **Microsoft PIX** are also on duty.
If you don't want install old SDK, you can open its distributive and extract `Utilities` folder. Executable name is `PIXWin.exe`.

Comment: I've used the graphics debugging, but didn't know about the Object Table. Thank you!

Comment: Theres also PIX in the DirectX SDK, which allows you to view all kind of resource.